# Why does using IIS7.5's Microsoft.Web.Management.dll only work in a 64bit process?

Tags: windows, iis, 64-bit, iis-7.5

I'm writing some code to permit users to remotely manage IIS7. Under the bonnet this adds authorisation rules to `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config` under the following config section:

> `system.webServer/management/authorization/authorizationRules`

I'm using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly and namespace with code similar to the following:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Management.Server;
...
ManagementAuthorization.Grant("MySiteUser, "My Web Site", false);
```

This code throws an exception if run in a 32 bit process, if built as 64 bit it runs fine:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message=Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/authorization' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`
```

However other server management tasks performed using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly and namespace work just fine in a 32 bit process, for example:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
....
int iisNumber = 60000;
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  var site = serverManager.Sites.Where(s => s.Id == iisNumber).SingleOrDefault();
  if (site != null)
  {
    site.Stop();
  }
}
```

Both these assemblies appear in the GAC and are pure MSIL (even though there is a COM interop layer to talk directly to IIS7's underlying management mechanisms).

The underlying configuration files `applicationHost.config` and `administration.config` are only visible to 64 bit editors (e.g. notepad.exe or NotePad2.exe) and I suspect that this is why my code can't modify `administration.config` via the `Microsoft.Web.Management`

Why does the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` allow me to read/modify `applicationHost.config` in a 32 bit process but `Microsoft.Web.Management` can only read/modify `administration.config` if run in a 64 bit process?

I am unable to recompile my project to target x64 because there is a dependency on a 32bit COM library that we don't have source for. I can build a work around which would involve making calls to an out of process 64 bit WCF app (or some such similar thing) but would prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging it looks like this is a bug:

This forum thread and a post by Carlos Aguilar explains all:

> http://forums.iis.net/p/1157779/1956471.aspx
>
> Now I understand the issue, what is
>   happening is that Cassini is a 32 bit
>   process and that in conjunction of a
>   bug in our configuration makes us try
>   to load the "redirected" syswow
>   (instead of system32) which is the
>   reason why we cannot find
>   administration.config. Running in 64
>   bit process alleviates the problem
>   cause there is no "magic" redirection
>   and we go to the right folder.

Any 32 bit process is going to encounter this roadhump.